# Extract value from json string data

Tags: jquery, html, json

I have the following JSON feed which is String data type.

```
"[
    {
        "str": "<ul><li>Item1<li><li>Item2<li><li>Item3<li><ul>"
    }
][
    {
        "str": "<ul><li>Teacher  Account<li><li>Student Account<li><ul>"
    }
][
    {
        "str": "<ul><li>Corporate<li><li>Accounts<li><ul>"
    }
]"
```

How can I get the values out so that I can append to the html element?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: your JSON is not valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't fetch data with this format which is wrong, your JSON data format should be like:

```
[
    {"str":"<ul><li>Item1</li><li>Item2</li><li>Item3</li></ul>"},
    {"str":"<ul><li>Teacher  Account</li><li>Student Account</li></ul>"},
    {"str":"<ul><li>Corporate</li><li>Accounts</li></ul>"}
];
```

then use

```
$.each( data, function(i, d){
    console.log(d.str);
});
```

Another thing i noticed that in your HTML Part that is also not in correct format, you just have to prepare your json data in correct format. you missed to close the `</li>` and `</ul>`;

here is the working demo http://jsfiddle.net/jogesh_pi/tN8AP/

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that my wrong JSON data format and missing </li> and </ul> tags. Figured out already. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery `.each()`

```
$.each(data, function( index, value ) {
  alert( index + ": " + value );
});
```

[More on jQuery .each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

Comment: Hi Rahul, thanks for your reply. I tried your suggestion but I get "TypeError: invalid 'in' operand obj" in jquery-latest.js

Answer (score 1):

this is wrong JSON string correct string should be like this

```
    var strJson = '[
     {"str": "<ul><li>Item1<li><li>Item2<li><li>Item3<li><ul>"},
     {"str": "<ul><li>Teacher  Account<li><li>Student Account<li><ul>"},
     {"str": "<ul><li>Corporate<li><li>Accounts<li><ul>"}
    ]'
```

and to access this string you can try this code.

```
var objJson = JSON.parse(strJson);
for(var index=0; index<objJson.length; index++) {
    alert(objJson[index].str);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `json` is `not valid` try this,

```
var json=[{"str": "<ul><li>Item1<li><li>Item2<li><li>Item3<li><ul>"},{"str": "<ul><li>Teacher  Account<li><li>Student Account<li><ul>"},{"str": "<ul><li>Corporate<li><li>Accounts<li><ul>"}];
$.each(json, function( i, v ) {
  console.log(v.str)
});
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YL24M/)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I wish I can accept more than one as answer.

Answer (score 1):

your JSON is not valid, validate your JSON **[HERE](http://jsonlint.com/)**

```
var a = '[
 {"str": "<ul><li>Item1<li><li>Item2<li><li>Item3<li><ul>"},
 {"str": "<ul><li>Teacher  Account<li><li>Student Account<li><ul>"},
 {"str": "<ul><li>Corporate<li><li>Accounts<li><ul>"}
]';
```

You can use for loop to fetch elements from JSON and append the elements

```
for(var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    $("div").append(json[i].str);
    console.log(json[i].str)
}
```

**[LIVE EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yashhy/q7hRj/)**

Comment: I did not realize my JSON feed was wrong. Thanks for pointing out.